# Cat file1 into file2 after specific pattern match

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have *file1* & *file2*, I want to `cat` *file1* into *file2* after match of `22` pattern. 
Can I do it with `cat` or I need to go for `awk` or `sed`

### file1

```
aa
bb
cc
```

### file2

```
11
22
33
44
```

---

### Resultant file2

```
11
22
aa
bb
cc
33
44
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '/22/r file1' file2
```

Answer (score 2):

For  completeness, here is an awk solution:

```
$ awk '{print;} /22/{system("cat file1");}' file2
11
22
aa
bb
cc
33
44
```

Comment: `awk '1;/22/{system("cat file1")}'` for shorter version.